# Лихой вид — это какой?

Tags: значение-слов

Попалось вот это высказывание Петра I:

[image]

И вопрос у меня о слове "лихой". Вроде как, оно означает либо "плохой", либо "удалой", но в каком значении оно употреблено тут?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, в значении позитивном. Представьте себя в роли начальника (есть опыт по жизни?). Подчинённые должны выглядеть в глазах начальника надёжными исполнителями, как джин из лампы: бравыми, удалыми, отважными. И не подвергающими сомнениям содержание распоряжений начальства. И свидетельством этому должна быть простота мины лица, тот самый синтезированный имидж по указу.

Comment: Непонятно, куда делся бегемотус. Вы, Hermit, не знаете?  
Кстати, в лампах обитают джиННы, но вам эта ошибка простительна, как технарю.

Comment: А джины обитают в бутылках))))

Answer (score 0):

> Подчинённые должны выглядеть в глазах начальника надёжными исполнителями...: бравыми, удалыми, отважными.

Но при этом должны иметь "придурковатый вид" Оригинально.